# Arduino ROS Issue

Tags: ros, arduino, rosserial, ros-lib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have generated ros_lib in arduino sketchbook, but when I compile the arduino code, It says "Error Compiling" and I get the error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/avr/4.5.3/../../../avr/bin/ld: HelloWorld.cpp.elf 
section `.text' will not fit in region `text' 
/usr/lib/gcc/avr/4.5.3/../../../avr/bin/ld: region `text' 
overflowed by 488 bytes collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

for all the ros_lib examples.

When I was running the code in the terminal for generating the arduino libraries, in the end I got the following error:

*** Warning, failed to generate libraries for the following packages: ***
map_msgs

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/115606/arduino-ros-issue/) by [samvrit](https://answers.ros.org/users/10541/samvrit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-01-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This error means that the code you're trying to compile won't fit into the flash memory of the device you're compiling it for.

If you can, try changing the target board to one with more flash.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [samvrit](https://answers.ros.org/users/10541/samvrit/) on 2014-01-08**:
You're right. I changed it and it worked. Thanks a lot!

**Comment by [nickosinski](https://answers.ros.org/users/10756/nickosinski/) on 2014-01-12**:
Noob question, but what do you mean by change "the target board" ...in the IDE tools menu? I did that and it didn't solve it for me, so I'm guessing somewhere else? Thanks in advance!

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-01-13**:
Yes; in the Arduino IDE, the Tools -> Board menu. Note that the board you select has to match the arduino you're programming.

**Comment by [nickosinski](https://answers.ros.org/users/10756/nickosinski/) on 2014-01-13**:
Thanks so much for your reply. To clarify, I don't get the "will not fit" error... just the error relating to "map_msgs"; is there a manual way to generate those libraries or should I just not worry about it? Thanks again - really appreciate it!

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-01-13**:
I wouldn't worry about not being able to build map_msgs, unless you're explicitly planning to use them in your project. They're probably too big to be useful on an arduino anyway.

**Comment by [nipun sachdeva](https://answers.ros.org/users/19015/nipun-sachdeva/) on 2014-06-26**:
ques; buddy i am getting the same problem but at the compilation time?
there is nothing to do with board , program is not even compiling ?
plz help

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-06-29**:
@nipun-sachdev : Unless you're seeing the exact same error message, I suggest you ask your question as a new question, and include the EXACT commands you're using and copy/paste the error message you're seeing.

If you're seeing the exact same error message, my answer still applies.